Didn't invoke the onBackgroundMessage function using FCM while receiving notification in IOS flutter
I have been work on the app where the notification are received form the firebase console when the notification arrive to the app the onBackgrouMeassage function is not running. I found the solution but all are the for the Cloud messaging SDK but didn't find any for the sending notification from the Firebase Console. So how to solve this? And I do all the things like apple certifications, configuration and other stuff.

Which version you are using of firebase_messaging
